# "My always account"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What does *my always account* mean?

The text where I read it is the following:

> Hello, I am [username], I would need to recover my always user [account name], I
>   have 4 years with yours, is lot of history, never happens any
>   inconvenience from me, my friends in drupal all people knows me for
>   [account name], and I need my user unblocked, so please consider it as a favour
>   to me.

Based on the text, I am inclined to think the person didn't use *always* in the correct way; is it really so? Is it grammatically correct to use *always* in that way, or is it normally used (even if in specific dialects, like Indian English, or British English)?
Would the phrase *my always account* be understood even if it doesn't refer to a user account on a website?

Comment: Can you provide some context please? This is not a common phrase, by any means :)

Comment: I am sorry; I forgot to report the sentence where I have read the phrase.

Comment: Just an FYI so inexperienced English speakers don't get confused, the block quote you've got there is fairly terribly broken English. Please don't try to draw any usage examples out of it.

Comment: Don't try to learn English from Nigerian scammers.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: Who wrote that is not a scammer, nor is he Nigerian. He is actually a regular user of a website, and he is Spanish.

Comment: @Dusty: I have actually heard _my always account_ in a conversation too, but I don't remember in which context was said, and the full sentence being said. What I reported is what I recently read; as I could report both the context and the full sentence, I preferred to report the sentence I read. That's all.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Yeah, I prefer that you showed the full context as it makes the meaning somewhat clearer, but the paragraph as a whole (not just the always account bit) is fairly awful English.  I just wanted to make it clear to someone who may not be as familiar with English that this wasn't a good paragraph to draw example usage from in general.  As to the *always account* phrase itself, I could imagine a usage where it would might sense in context, but I'm not sure this is it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it's an expression that exist in the persons native language, but doesn't translate directly into english.

My guess is that the intended meaning would be *the user account that I always have used* or *the user account that I have used from the beginning*.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't give any more context than that, I'd have to say *always* account meant *permanent* or *daily-use* account. This might draw a distinction between a *sometimes* account or a *temporary* account. As I say, though, a larger context would help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about bank accounts I'd say a better phrase would be:

> Every day account

To refer to the account you use for regular expenses.